# How to instantiate a callback in an ActionCreator when using redux-thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

In the following code the 'callback' parameter is a function in my component that called the action creator, however I cannot seem to work out where to evoke this callback in my action creator. I'm using ReduxThunk for the async functionality.

My main objective is to fire the callback after the successful request is made.

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const FETCH_USERS = 'FETCH_USERS';
const API_URL_TOP30 = 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent';
const API_URL_ALLTIME = 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/alltime';

export function fetchUsers(list, callback) {
  const apicall = (list) ? API_URL_ALLTIME : API_URL_TOP30
  const data = ''
  const request = axios.get(apicall)

  return (dispatch) => {
    request.then(({data}) => {
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_USERS, payload: data })
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invoke the callback in `then` method

```
export function fetchUsers(list, callback) {
    const apicall = (list) ? API_URL_ALLTIME : API_URL_TOP30
    const data = ''
    const request = axios.get(apicall)

    return (dispatch) => {
        request.then(({ data }) => {
            callback(data);
            dispatch({ type: FETCH_USERS, payload: data })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ali, such a n00b mistake by me. One of my components that was calling the Action Creator didn't contain a callback function which caused console errors and confuzed the hell out of me :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a callback as a second parameter to your function, you could just return your promise from that function.

```
 export function fetchUsers(list) {
  const apicall = (list) ? API_URL_ALLTIME : API_URL_TOP30
  const data = ''
  const request = axios.get(apicall)

  return (dispatch) => {
   return request.then(({data}) => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_USERS, payload: data })
   })
  }
}
```

This makes it possible to use .then() from your component, since your function returns a promise.

```
*** Your component ***
fetchUsers(list).then(() => { 
 console.log('success')
})
```